# React navigation v2 swipe

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

Since updating to react navigation v2 when I'm inside a stack navigator I can swipe between tabs and now I don't know how to solve it because gesturesEnabled doesn't work for me anymore.

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home:HomeScreen,
    Read:Read
    },
    {
        headerMode:'none'
    }
);

const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
        Home:{
            screen: HomeStack,    
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel:'Home',
                tabBarIcon: () => <Image source ={require('../assets/icons/tabHome.png')} style={{width: 32,height: 32}}></Image>
              }
        },
    {
        initialRoutName: 'Home',
        swipeEnabled: true
    });
export const Root = createStackNavigator ({
    Tabs: {
        screen: Tabs
        }
    },
    {
        navigationOptions:{
            header: <Header/>
        }
    }

);

HomeStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    let tabBarVisible = true;
    if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
      tabBarVisible = false;
    }
    return {
      tabBarVisible
    };
};
class MainScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Root />
    }
}
```

So what I really need is to disable swipe between tabs when I'm inside Read stack.
Also as you can see root options has a fixed header. How can I hide the header when I'm inside root? because header:'none' doesn't overwrite the root option.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set `swipeEnabled` to `false` in your tab navigator config.  This is documented in the docs here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html

Comment: I want to keep swiping outside for tabs. Now even if I'm inside a stack I can swipe the tabs from inside.